# Angular 5 - Event emitter (Property 'update' does not exist on type ....)

Tags: angular5, angular-cli, angular-event-emitter

I've got a component that I want to update when a person's name changes by emitting an event. My problem is the code doesn't compile because of an error. This is my code

**ApplicationFormComponent**

```
@Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();

 closeAccordion(isComplete: string, accordionToClose: string, accordion: NgbAccordion) {
    if (accordionToClose === 'personal-details-panel') {
      this.applicationStatusFlags.personalDetailsStatus = (isComplete === 'true');
      this.nameChange.emit({ personId: this.personId });
    }
}
```

**ApplicationFormComponent.html**

```
 <name-display
        [personId]="personId" 
        [placeHolderText]="'Hello'" 
        (nameChange)="update($event)">
 </name-display>
```

**NameDisplayComponent**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { PersonService } from "../../../service/person.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'name-display',
  templateUrl: './NameDisplay.component.html',
  providers: [PersonService]
})

export class NameDisplayComponent implements OnChanges {

  constructor(private readonly personService: PersonService) { }
  @Input() personId;
  @Input() placeHolderText: string = "";

  forename: string = "";

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes["personId"]) {
      this.personService.getPersonDetails(this.personId).subscribe((res: IPersonDetails) => {
        this.forename = res.forenames;
      });
    }
  };


  update(personId: number) {
    alert("update name");
    this.personService.getPersonDetails(personId).subscribe((res: IPersonDetails) => {
      this.forename = res.forenames;
    });
  }

}
```

My problem is basically when I use angular cli with the command ng server --aot, it doesn't compile because of this error:

```
ERROR in src\app\component\ApplicationForm\ApplicationForm.component.html(42,9): : Property 'update' does not exist on type 'ApplicationFormComponent'.
```

I've written a similar component that uses an event emitter which doesn't have this problem, so I'm stuck with how to fix the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are passing $event to method.

```
(nameChange)="update($event)"
```

But it accepts number.

```
update(personId: number) {
    alert("update name");
}
```

Please change the method as below.

```
update(event:any) {
    const personId = event as number
    alert("update name");
 }
```